# Why do we have 4 permission argument in TCL I/O?

Tags: file, permissions, arguments, tcl, chmod

In TCL there are four permission arguments of file. I want to open a new file and give permissions. Look following example:

```
open file_name.txt w 0666
```

We have permissions for the file owner/group/other in Linux. Why do we use 4 arguments in TCL? What is the fourth one (I am not sure it is the first one or last)?

Answer (score 2):

The `permissions` argument is an integer representing 3 groups of 3 bits for owner/group/other. So rw permissions for all 3 groups would be 110110110 in binary. In decimal, that's 438. But that's not very obvious. This is why the argument is usually specified in octal. The old way to indicate that a number should be interpreted as octal is by adding a leading 0. But to be future proof, you better use 0o666 nowadays.

Comment: Indeed, one can use `0b110110110` to see the bit-wise permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `open`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm) does say that acceptable argument patterns are:

> **open** *fileName*
> **open** *fileName access*
> **open** *fileName access permissions*

And goes on to define *permissions* as:

> If a new file is created as part of opening it, *permissions* (an integer) is used to set the permissions for the new file in conjunction with the process's file mode creation mask. *Permissions* defaults to 0666.

The arguments mostly map fairly closely to the arguments to the Unix `open()` system call and `fopen()` library call. It's pretty rare that you actually specify the *permissions* (and that's modified by your umask; Tcl doesn't expose any way of working with that) as the defaults usually work well for most applications.

If you need to alter the permissions of a file you've made, try [`file attributes`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M6):

```
# I prefer the symbolic permissions descriptors supported by this command
file attributes $fileName -permissions rw-rw-rw-
```

Comment: It would be nice if `open` took the symbolic form too.

Comment: @Shawn You would have to redesign the symbolic form in some way then, probably with way more typing. As it is now, it's more confusing and has more probability to create a bug, compared to the octal representation.

Comment: @potrzebie I'd imagine the relevant `file attributes` code could just be reused.

Comment: @Shawn My concern is that the *nix symbolic form is too complex, in a way that leads you to believe that it's simple, and therefore leaves too much room for potential bugs. Perhaps you can compare it to `scanf()` being misused in C. IMO, if you need to use permissions when creating a file, you should know the octal system and pay attention to every digit.